# How can I return data to an AJAX call with Perl?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, perl

I have a HTML file, which generates a web page. Users can enter some comments on webgpage. To save the comments i am calling a perl script, using JQuery/ AJAX.  which will add one row in DB.

Inside perl script after adding the record, i am again fetching the same record. Now i want to display that record in my page without refreshing the page. (i know we can do using append in jquery) My question is how to return that record from perl to HTML page, including HTML tags and all.

This is the portion where new records will be added.

```
<span class="requester"> 
    <span>**message**</span> 
    </br>
    <i> - **username**  </i>
    <button class="deleteResponse" id="id"> delete </button> 
    <hr>
 </span>
```

Message and username is the items i will be getting from MYSQL quesry.\

This is what i am using to display the data.

```
 $("#"+getpID+" textarea ").before(htmlcode).fadeIn();
```

and htmlcode is

```
var htmlcode = '<span class="requester"> <span>message</span> </br>     <i> - username 0 seconds ago </i> <button class="deleteResponse" id="id"> delete </button> <hr> </span>';
```

Instead of htmlcode i want data should be returned from perl script.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks sapna

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I am able to display hardcoded data. I want to display returned data from perl, and dont know how to return HTML code from perl

Comment: If you call it with jQuery's AJAX, just print a valid header and the data. jQuery will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Perl script needs to print the data you want returned by your AJAX call. It's basic CGI.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new;

# do your database stuff here

my $result = "HTML CODE"; # this is your result

print $cgi->header('text/html');
print $result;
```

In your [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), do something like this (which I party lifted from the jQuery doc):

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $("#"+getpID+" textarea ").before(data).fadeIn();
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Please note that I did not test this.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested..... This line throwing an exception.   **my $result = "<span class="requester"> <span>message</span> </br>  <i> - username 0 seconds ago </i> <button class="deleteResponse" id="id"> delete #</button> <hr> </span>"; ** # this is your result

Comment: What kind of error? You cannot use `"` inside your string if you quote the string with `"`. Use the [qq-operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qq.html) instead. Here doc should also work, but [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) says that *If the terminating string is quoted, the type of quotes used determine the treatment of the text.*, so do not use `'`, just leave them out!

Comment: No, you have not. It was deleted because it was not an answer. Please edit your question and add an update. But the above comment should fix your issue, anyway.

Comment: After solving that issue, I have one more problem, the HTML code i want to return contains some variables. How to embed perl in HTMl in this case? Simbabque, can you please help me in this matter?

Comment: I already did. What you posted was ok, you just have to remove the `'` from the `<<'HERE'` part because Perl treats it like a single quote `'string'` that does not fill in your vars. Either say `<<HERE` or `<<"HERE"` or just use `qq` (see above).